# How to change to another Activity when pressing on a Gridviewpager?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridview, wear-os

I am trying to start a new certain Activity based on which page I am clicking on in a Gridview. 
I tried to understand the Sample GridViewPager which is coming along with the sdk and trying to adapt the [given explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343337/android-wear-gridviewpager-onclick-listener). But I really don't know how to bring these two things together and even where to start.

The first java.file Selection

```
public class Selection extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection_grid);
        final GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setAdapter(new Workers(this, getFragmentManager()));
        DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
        dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
    }
}
```

and the second java.file Users:

```
public class Users extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {

    private static final int TRANSITION_DURATION_MILLIS = 100;

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<Row> mRows;
    private ColorDrawable mDefaultBg;

    private ColorDrawable mClearBg;

    public Users (Context ctx, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = ctx;

        mRows = new ArrayList<Workers.Row>();

        mRows.add(new Row(cardFragment(R.string.title, R.string.user1)));
        mRows.add(new Row(cardFragment(R.string.title, R.string.user2)));
        mRows.add(new Row(cardFragment(R.string.title, R.string.user3)));
        mRows.add(new Row(cardFragment(R.string.title, R.string.user4)));

//      In case in one row several cardFragments are needed
//        mRows.add(new Row(
//                cardFragment(R.string.cards_title, R.string.cards_text),
//                cardFragment(R.string.expansion_title, R.string.expansion_text)));

        mDefaultBg = new ColorDrawable(R.color.dark_grey);
        mClearBg = new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
    }


    LruCache<Integer, Drawable> mRowBackgrounds = new LruCache<Integer, Drawable>(3) {
        @Override
        protected Drawable create(final Integer row) {
            int resid = BG_IMAGES[row % BG_IMAGES.length];
            new DrawableLoadingTask(mContext) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                    TransitionDrawable background = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                            mDefaultBg,
                            result
                    });
                    mRowBackgrounds.put(row, background);
                    notifyRowBackgroundChanged(row);
                    background.startTransition(TRANSITION_DURATION_MILLIS);
                }
            }.execute(resid);
            return mDefaultBg;
        }
    };


   private Fragment cardFragment(int titleRes, int textRes) {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        CardFragment fragment =
                CardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));
        // Add some extra bottom margin to leave room for the page indicator
        fragment.setCardMarginBottom(
                res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_margin_bottom));
        return fragment;

-----------------Changed part -  Start (deleted the above part of the method)----------------
//        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
//        MyCardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));
-----------------Changed part -  End------------------
        }


 static final int[] BG_IMAGES = new int[] {
            R.drawable.user1,
            R.drawable.user2,
            R.drawable.user3,
            R.drawable.user4
    };


  /** A convenient container for a row of fragments. */
    private class Row {
        final List<Fragment> columns = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        public Row(Fragment... fragments) {
            for (Fragment f : fragments) {
                add(f);
            }
        }

        public void add(Fragment f) {
            columns.add(f);
        }

        Fragment getColumn(int i) {
            return columns.get(i);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {
        Row adapterRow = mRows.get(row);
        return adapterRow.getColumn(col);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getBackgroundForRow(final int row) {
        return mRowBackgrounds.get(row);
    }


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return mRows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int rowNum) {
        return mRows.get(rowNum).getColumnCount();
    }

    class DrawableLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Drawable> {
        private static final String TAG = "Loader";
        private Context context;

        DrawableLoadingTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading asset 0x" + Integer.toHexString(params[0]));
            return context.getResources().getDrawable(params[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Third java.file MyCardFragment

```
public class MyCardFragment extends CardFragment {

private View fragmentView;

@Override
protected View onCreateContentView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentView = super.onCreateContentView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return fragmentView;
}

public void setOnClickListener(final View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.fragmentView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

}
```

UPDATE LOGCAT:

```
02-24 13:53:18.149    3104-3104/de.denjo.fragmentapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.denjo.fragmentapplication, PID: 3104
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.denjo.fragmentapplication/android.text.Selection}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
            at de.denjo.fragmentapplication.MainActivity.OnClickSelection(MainActivity.java:35)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: is there any further information needed?

Comment: I would suggest setting `OnClickListener` on each fragment you adding to `GridViewPager`.

Comment: the problem is, that I honestly really don`t have an idea how to do so for each fragment.

Comment: That is quite easy, I suppose, then you are creating fragment, you are inflating layout, right? So just set listener on the inflated view:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

Extend CardFragment:

```
class MyCardFragment extends CardFragment {

     private View fragmentView;     
     private OnClickListener listener;

     @Override
     protected View onCreateContentView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         fragmentView = super.onCreateContentView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
         fragmentView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(final View view) {
                 if (listener != null) {
                     listener.onClick(view);
                 }
             }    

         }
         return fragmentView;
     }

     public void setOnClickListener(final OnClickListener listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
     }

}
```

That's all :)

UPD (and also look at updated MyCardFragment or you will get NullPointerException!):

```
private Fragment cardFragment(int titleRes, int textRes) {
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        final MyCardFragment fragment = MyCardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));
        fragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(final View view) {
                    //do everything you want
                    //here you've got access to clicked fragment
             }

        }
        return fragment;
}
```

Comment: probably that's an amateur question, but how will I be able to make it individual? for example when clicking on the fragment (1,0) or (2,2)?

Comment: There is plenty of things you can do. The simpliest thing is to pass the position of fragment to the fragment creator method and then save it. And then create method getFragmentPosition() and call it from listener's onClick()

Comment: Sorry for asking so late: just had the chance to look up all your suggestions. I am not sure where to create the "MyFragment"-class. Isn`t it acutally in the FragmentManager (see my code)? And how do I pass the position?

Comment: 1) Yes, substitute your `CardFragment fragment = CardFragment.create(res.getText(titleRes), res.getText(textRes));` with something like `MyCardFragment.create(...)`. 
2) You know the position of fragment, then you are creating one, aren't you? And btw, why don't just use `setOnClickListener` method, to handle clicks? Also see my updated answer: I changed `onCreateContentView` method and you will not need to inflate view yourself.

Comment: Okay, I tried the following: 
I created a new public class with the code you posted in you answer. (by now I do have 3 classes for opening a Gridviewpager). Also substituted the CardFragment part in my Fragment method. But yeah, its not working. You see I am a raw recruit and really don`t know what I have to do. Could you somehow fix your answer on my problem. Anyway, I will reward your help with the reputation.

Comment: Have you tried setting OnClickListener? Could you post your updated code?

Comment: I have added the changed part and the edit. I declared it in the code with -----Changed part ------ and the third class with the EDIT.

Comment: Oh, I am feeling so amateur. So am I deleting the "first" and "second" java.file?

Comment: Basically I want to have 5 fragments in a gridviewpager, being able to click on them and passing a value to the next activity. :)

Comment: Why would you delete them? In onClick method just call `startActivity` method with `Intent` which contains extras. For example:
`Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("OBJECT_NAME", someObject);
startActivity(i);`

Comment: I added your code into the "users"-class. unfortunately this is not working, because I am not able to activate the new class in the manifest. What could that possible be?

Comment: What does it mean: "I am not able to activate the new class in the manifest"?

Comment: I uploaded the project on [github](https://github.com/kla4dj/FragmentApplication)

Comment: But you didn't explain what you mean by "I am not able to activate the new class in the manifest"

Comment: I am getting an ActivityNotFoundException. My logcat asks me if I have declared the activity in the manifest.

Comment: @DenJo, hard to tell, your manifest looks OK for me. Please post full exception trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71592/discussion-between-den-jo-and-semyon-danilov).